# In Python (Including Sqlite) pulling information from a database using it as a variable and using it issues

Tags: python, sqlite

So i'm having a problem here with this snippit of code. The database isnt the problem and is completely populated. Now it is supposed to bring up the console/command line where i can then input the information as required. 
For example the question in the question database is:

> "Over the last two weeks have you have symptoms of the flu?"

Currently this piece of code doesn't produce anything and i'm fairly new to python coding when i changed from a dictionary of questions to then adding them into a database and trying to pull them from the database. I do know the problem is in the first lines of code as running from the dictionary the code has worked previously.

#Question1

```
    conn.execute("SELECT question from question WHERE questionID = '1'")
    question1 = conn.fetchone()

    # print the question

    print (question1())

    # use the question 1 choices to get an answer

    answer = input(question1.get()).lower()
```

## Anything under here has no issues i do not believe.

```
    if answer == question1.get(answer):



        c = conn.execute("SELECT illnessID, Illness, illnessinfo from illnesses WHERE illness = 'Flu'")



        for row in c:

            print( "Illness Identifier = ", row[0])

            print( "Suspected Illness= ", row[1])

            print( "Displayed Symptom = ", row[2])

            print("Thanks this has been recorded.")

            ident = ident + " - " + row[1]



        c = conn.execute("SELECT drugID, drug from drugs WHERE drug = 'Flu injection'")

        for row in c:   

            print( "Drug = ", row[0])

            print( "Drug = ", row[1])

            pescr = pescr + " - " + row[1]

            print(ident)

            print(pescr)

            print("\n")

    else:

        print("Okay Next question.")
```

## Under here is an exmaple of the database for the specific question

```
    c.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO question(questionID, question) VALUES(1,'Over the last two weeks have you have symptoms of the flu?')")


c.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO choices (choicesID, choices) VALUES(1,'Yes')")
c.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO choices (choicesID, choices) VALUES(2,'No')")


c.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO answer (answerID, answer) VALUES(1,'Yes')")
c.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO answer (answerID, answer) VALUES(2,'No')")
```

Comment: Not enough info for an answer, when you say "this piece of code doesn't produce anything" I understand that nothing is printed at all, is that correct? do you have some error printed?

Comment: Oh sorry, Yes when ran nothing appears, nothing is printed. No error or anything at all it's as if it never ran.

Comment: This `print (question1())` is sketchy, based on what the [expected return value of `fetchone`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone) is.

Comment: @JBell How do you Ran the script? from cmd, Idle, pycharm, other?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is `print (question1())` should be replaced by `print (question1)`

question1 should contain a tuple which is not callable.

But that should have given you an error...